Excluding all results where any item in a second joined table are in a given list
I have an sql query:
SELECT
oi.order_id, oi.item_id, oi.item_description, ois.status_code, s.status_name, ois.status_date,
FROM_UNIXTIME(ois.status_date) AS status_date_readable,  ois.employee_code, ois.qc_fail, ois.`comment`
FROM
order_item AS oi
INNER JOIN order_item_status AS ois ON oi.order_id = ois.order_id
INNER JOIN `status` AS s ON ois.status_code = s.status_code
WHERE
oi.ship_date = 0 AND oi.date_in > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2024-01-01 00:00:00')
ORDER BY oi.order_id ASC, oi.item_id ASC, ois.status_date ASC;

This gets order status updates for orders that have not been shipped (which equates to ship_date = 0)
The problem is, that for any given 'order_item' record, there are multiple order_item_status records.  And some of those status records include a status update that shows the order was cancelled.  Orders that have been cancelled also have ship_date = 0
The status codes for 'cancelled' include 140 and 141
So basically i need to exclude ALL matches for any combination of order_id + item_id that includes a single status with status_code 140 or 141.  I'm not sure how to do that.
No idea where to begin.

Do you need to exclude the entire order, or just those items?

Shouldn't the join with order_item_status also include the item_id column?

Add LEFT JOIN that matches the conditions you want to exclude, and use the LEFT JOIN+NULL pattern
SELECT
oi.order_id, oi.item_id, oi.item_description, ois.status_code, s.status_name, ois.status_date,
FROM_UNIXTIME(ois.status_date) AS status_date_readable,  ois.employee_code, ois.qc_fail, ois.`comment`
FROM
order_item AS oi
INNER JOIN order_item_status AS ois ON oi.order_id = ois.order_id
INNER JOIN `status` AS s ON ois.status_code = s.status_code
LEFT JOIN order_item_status AS ois2 
    ON oi.order_id = ois2.order_id AND oi.item_id = ois2.item_id 
        AND ois2.status_code IN (140, 141)
WHERE
    oi.ship_date = 0 AND oi.date_in > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2024-01-01 00:00:00')
    AND ois2.order_id IS NULL
ORDER BY oi.order_id ASC, oi.item_id ASC, ois.status_date ASC;


the problem is that there are multiple status entries per order item and not all of them are going to be 140 or 141. I was able to figure out a query that got me the results I needed by using a where (SELECT) that counted results from status where status_code IN ... (haven't had time to post it)

ah, but re-reading I think I see what yours is doing. I may play with that later. Thanks
